# Understanding the behavior of HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS with the following attribute to the body tag and header:

```
body
{
    font-size: 0.87em;
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Georgia, Verdana, Tahoma, Microsoft Sans Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div#header
{
    width:1024px;
    margin:5px auto;
    height:180px;
    background-color: rgb(91,25,79);
}
div.headerLeft
{
    height:100%;
    width:850px;
    border-right:10px solid rgb(169, 171, 174);
    background-color: rgb(124,71,111);
}
div#footer
{
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    font-size: 1.27em;

}
div#content
{
    margin:auto 40px;
    width:200;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

In my HTML I have the following structure for the body:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="headerLeft" />
    </div>
    <div id="waycontact">

        <div class="contactPaula">
            <p>paulaMACHADO</p>
            <p>crea 97877/D-MG</p>
            <p>(31) 8725 5393</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contactBeatriz">
            <p>beatrizDAMAS</p>

            <p>crea 94660/D-MG</p>
            <p>(31) 9216 6968</p>
        </div>
        <div class="address">
            <p>av. álvares cabral, 381, sl. 604, centro - belo horizonte - mg</p>
            <p>cep: 30170-000 - telefax: (31) 3222 0345</p>
            <p><a class="remove-linkcss" href="mailto:amsd_arq@yahoo.com.br">amsd_arq@yahoo.com.br</a></p>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

<img class="left space" alt="Arquitetura" src="http://cdn.archdaily.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/1265154380_107-silos-090511-west-view-a4-allard-architecture-528x304.jpg" />
<h2>Sobre a empresa</h2>
<p>A AMSD é focada em qualidade..</p>



    </div>

    <div id="footer">

        <a class="current" href="#">home</a>
        <span class="space">|</span>
        <a href="#">quem somos</a>
        <span class="space">|</span>
        <a href="#">blog</a>
        <span class="space">|</span>

        <a href="#">na mídia</a>
        <span class="space">|</span>
        <a href="#">contato</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/PQyZY/) you can see the complete code of the page.

In CSS you can completely see it has a class called ".redborder" her March the HTML element with a red border.
Note that the body marked with red.
But the end result I noticed that the body is contemplating only the header. why he will not until the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

`<div class="headerLeft" />`

to correct (HTML and "marketing" XHTML):

```
<div class="headerLeft"></div>
```

More information http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_3

Also add missing `</div>` (for `<div id="header">`). After this it should be ok.

Comment: I think it's controversial thesis. Ok, It is valid against XHTML 1.0 DTDs (Strict, Transitional and Frameset), because in XML it doesn't matter how you write empty elements, but from point of web browsing it is incorrect (with exception of "true" empty elements such as hr, br etc.). Note that about 99% of web pages serves XHTML as text/html mime (even http://www.w3.org/).

Comment: Okay, but the question is why the body does not go to the bottom of the page, and how to get it covers the entire page with the red border.

Comment: @Riderman de Sousa Barbosa You are right. I found there is also missing </div>. After you add it, red border is for whole body.

Comment: Wow, it worked, thanks.

but I really do not understand why this happens.

Comment: When I put oo </ div> the site disarray, how do I leave the site aligned to the center?

Comment: @Riderman de Sousa Barbosa You can put margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto for every div you need to be centered (more concise margin: 0 auto; or generally margin: someValue auto;). Another way to achieve it is to make one main div container (i.e. aligned to center) and put other divs in it. I learned that writing proper (X)HTML code makes life easier (there is no guarantee how improper code behaves). You can use for example Html Validator Firefox plugin. Also Firebug could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I have miss-interpreted the question, but you want the red border to stretch all the way over the content?

If so, a way I have found to achieve this is to simply add a `clear: both;` attribute to the last div you want covered by the red border div.

Appologies is this is not the question you wanted answeri

Comment: The last div (footer div) is already marked with clear: both. What I want is to understand why the body is not covering the whole page?
And as it does to the body covering the entire page.
Not excuse, feel free to ask questions.